# How to select Particular Array value in javascript when there is multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here i have code where I'm generating random number and selecting particular drop down list.How can i choose particular array of selected list.

```
function myfunction(){
  var selectedList=document.getElementById("selectedId").value;
  var result=generateRandomNumber();
      allArrays(result,selectedList);
}

function allArrays(result,selectedList){
  var fruitsArray=["apple","banana","mango","jack","kiwi"];
  var sportsArray=["cricket","baseball","volleyball","football","tennis"];
  var animalsArray=["monkey","donkey","dog","cat","rat"];
  var playersArray=["sachin","watson","gale","akram","narine"];
}

function generateRandomNumber(){
  var numberResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
  return numberResult ;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectedId">
  <option value="fruits" onclick="myfunction(this.value)">fruits</option>
  <option value="sports" onclick="myfunction(this.value)">sports</option>
  <option value="animals" onclick="myfunction(this.value)">animals</option>
  <option value="players" onclick="myfunction(this.value)">players</option>
</select>
```

For example: if i selected fruits option from drop down in an alert i will get fruits, then i'm generating random number. According to that generated random Number how can i get respective value from perticular (selected list array) and other arrays has not to be initialized un necessarily?

Comment: if i write separate functions for each array type,my problem will be solve.But as per my requirement i should not use individual functions for each array type.And in Common function(allArrays)selected listarray only has to be initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution :

HTML:

```
<select id="selectedId">
    <option value="fruits" onclick="myfunction(this.value)">fruits</option>
    <option value="sports" onclick="myfunction(this.value)">sports</option>
    <option value="animals" onclick="myfunction(this.value)">animals</option>
    <option value="players" onclick="myfunction(this.value)">players</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myfunction(res) {
    var array = allArrays(res);
    var result = generateRandomNumber(array.length);
    var randomItem = array[result];
    console.log(randomItem);
}

function allArrays(result) {
    var arrays = {
        fruitsArray: ["apple", "banana", "mango", "jack", "kiwi"],
        sportsArray: ["cricket", "baseball", "volleyball", "football", "tennis"],
        animalsArray: ["monkey", "donkey", "dog", "cat", "rat"],
        playersArray: ["sachin", "watson", "gale", "akram", "narine"]
    }
    return arrays[result + 'Array'];
}

function generateRandomNumber(length) {
    var numberResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
    return numberResult;
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zp55sc6e/)

But you should not use `onclick` nor `onchange` attributes in HTML :

HTML:

```
<select id="selectedId">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="fruits">fruits</option>
    <option value="sports">sports</option>
    <option value="animals">animals</option>
    <option value="players">players</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addEvent(elt, event, func) {
   if (elt.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
      elt.addEventListener(event,func,false);
   else if (elt.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
      elt.attachEvent("on"+event, func);
   }
}

function myfunction(e) {
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var value = target.value;
    if (!value)
        return;
    var array = allArrays(target.value);
    var result = generateRandomNumber(array.length);
    var randomItem = array[result];
    console.log(randomItem);
}

function allArrays(result) {
    var arrays = {
        fruitsArray: ["apple", "banana", "mango", "jack", "kiwi"],
        sportsArray: ["cricket", "baseball", "volleyball", "football", "tennis"],
        animalsArray: ["monkey", "donkey", "dog", "cat", "rat"],
        playersArray: ["sachin", "watson", "gale", "akram", "narine"]
    }
    return arrays[result + 'Array'];
}

function generateRandomNumber(length) {
    var numberResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
    return numberResult;
}

addEvent(window, 'load', function(e) {
    var selectId = document.getElementById('selectedId');
    addEvent(selectId, 'change', myfunction);
});
```

Deom [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zp55sc6e/4/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, move the definitions out of the function, or they won't be accessible at all.

Now that they're global, you can access them like:

```
window[selectedList + 'array']
```

Comment: Scimonster, i dont want to write each array in different functions.Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

First remove the `onclick`s from your `option`s inline HTML.

```
<select id="selectedId">
  <option value="fruits">fruits</option>
  <option value="sports">sports</option>
  <option value="animals">animals</option> 
  <option value="players">players</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

Then using JavaScipt attach `onclick` events to your `option`s. We use `[].slice.call` to convert the nodelist to an array so we can use `forEach` over it.

```
var options = document.querySelectorAll('option');

[].slice.call(options).forEach(function (option) {
  option.onclick = myfunction;
});
```

The neatest way of containing the arrays is to keep them in an object:

```
var arrays = {
  fruits: ["apple","banana","mango","jack","kiwi"],
  sports: ["cricket","baseball","volleyball","football","tennis"],
  animals: ["monkey","donkey","dog","cat","rat"],
  players: ["sachin","watson","gale","akram","narine"]
}
```

For function that runs when the `select` is changed:

```
function myfunction() {

  // grab the select element
  var select = document.getElementById("selectedId");

  // Get the value of the selected index, say "fruit"
  var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

  // and grab that array from the object of arrays
  var array = arrays[value];
  alert(array);

  // Then pluck a random element from the chosen array
  var result = array[generateRandomNumber()];
  alert(result);
}

function generateRandomNumber(){
  var numberResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
  return numberResult ;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqfL32u0/19/)

Comment: @Andy.By this way, all arrays wont initialize right?only selected array will initialized remaining will not initialized right.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by initialise @GangadharB. The arrays are all created within the object. `myFunction` just selects one based on the `select` value and then grabs an element from it.

Comment: ,what i mean:When i select fruits from list at that time only fruits array will be loaded.

Comment: `value` is the name of the array from the option you've chosen. `var array = arrays[value]` is where it just grabs that array based on the object key.

Comment: Andy,can you check one error is there in your code.select fruit first time than again select fruit.second time not working.

Comment: It is `onchange`. So the selection has to be different each time.

Comment: @GangadharB, I've amended the code back to having `onclick` on the options. This works now. Demo updated.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: ,i'm using Firefox latest version